# can't running rake assets:precompile in rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, precompile

when i'm try run

```
rake assets:precompile RAILS_ENV=production
```

i get error like this :

```
rake aborted!
Sprockets::ArgumentError: Asset logical path has no extension: ~application
```

in my config/environtments/production.rb :

```
config.assets.compile = true
```

why i get error like this?

Comment: It is looking like you have a malformed sprocket line in one of your assets.

Comment: You're welcome. You should add an answer to this with the fix you made so it can help others.

Answer (score 1):

@adamk33n3r has it right here, sprockets doesn't understand one of the files in your asset pipeline. It looks like you accidently save a file with a '.~application' extension.

Answer (score 0):

Move any folders/files without extensions out of app/assets and into vendor/assets (or anywhere else rails can find them). This is a known issue with sprockets and bower has a warning about it on their readme see https://github.com/stve/bower/pull/4/files